# Explanation for bash command

Tags: bash, sed, stringstream

I know what is the function of the bash commands but i need some explanation to the regex.
the bash should be able to iterate through text files in the current directory and remove blank lines.

```
$sed '/^$/d` -i *txt
```

sed = **s**tream **ed**itor

what does the '/^$/d` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a regular expression, and the action is that it deletes matching lines. (`/d`). The regex matches empty lines -- `^` is "beginning of line" and `$` is "end of line"

Comment: how about the ' and ` what's the difference?

Comment: The backtick is command expansion. Whatever you copied this from is using the wrong quote mark. It's quoted with `'` to escape certain characters from the shell (`$`). As it is, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Daenyth. the back ` must have came from the bash for dir-d` sorry. it should have been this $sed '/^$/d' -i *txt ??